# HTML elements moving on resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I have looked around at google and looked at another question: [Page elements moving on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605819/page-elements-moving-on-window-resize) and I still cannot find the answer to this. My problem is that when I resize the browser my top div element where my navigation bar is moves messing up how the website looks. Since the CSS has it a certain amount to the right CSS probably updates how the page looks since I am resizing it. How would I keep the elements from moving upon page resizing?

My current code

```
         <div id="top" style="background-image: url(images/Home/space.gif); height: 120px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
            <a href="contact.html">
            <img id="buttoncontact" alt="Contact" src="images\Logo\contact.png">
            </a>
            <a id="plugins" alt="Plugins" href="http://bukkit.org/" target="_blank"> +Bukkit</a>
            <a href="home.html"><img id="bukkiticon" src="images\Logo\bukkit.png"></a>
            <a id="twitter" alt="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"> +Twitter</a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img id="twittericon" src="images\Logo\twitter.png"></a>
            <a id="youtube" alt="YouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"> +YouTube</a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img id="yticon" src="images\Logo\youtube.png"></a>
            <img id="td6img" src="images\Logo\TD6.png">
            <nav id="navigation">
                <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="contact.html">
                    <img src="images\Home\mars.png">
                </a>
                <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="projects.html">
                    <img src="images\Home\merc.png">
                </a>
                <a id="navigation-anchor-current" href="home.html">
                    <img src="images\Home\sun.png">
                </a>
                <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="lessons.html">
                    <img src="images\Home\nept.png">
                </a>
                <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="donate.html">
                    <img src="images\Home\jupiter.png">
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#top
{
    background-image: url("images/Home/stars.png");
    height: 95px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    z-index: 100;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(44,44,44,.3);
}
#buttoncontact
{
    float:left;
}
#yticon
{
    position:absolute;
    right:300px;
}

#youtube
{
text-decoration:none;
position:absolute;
right:225px;
color:red;
}

#twittericon
{
position:absolute;
right:190px;
}

#twitter
 {
 text-decoration:none;
 position:absolute;
 right:130px;
 color:aqua;
 }

#bukkiticon
{
position:absolute;
right:95px;
}

#plugins
{
text-decoration:none;
position:absolute;
right:35px;
color:#FF8000;
}
#navigation
{
    text-align:center;
}
#navigation-anchor-normal
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:aqua;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 8px;
}
#navigation-anchor-current
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:aqua;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 8px;
}
```

The only element that is not moving is the TD6img above the nav. Everything else is moving when I resize the window.

What I want to accomplish is having these elements stay put upon resizing the window and not move with the resizing.

This is only happening to this div element no other div element that I have under it.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a responsive design? what is the width of your webpage?

Comment: To represent better the problem, provide a `http://jsfiddle.net` link and include only the relevant part here. This way you'll  get better answers (and upvotes?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is creating a responsive site.

I highly suggest you to use existing framework for that, and not trying to redo all by your self.

For that, look at [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) that is the most robust and efficient jquery / javascript responsive design framework.

Comment: Can you suggest me any tutorials to this? I am very very new to jquery/javascript.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/ is pretty well explained. it is very important that you understand how a page is divided by 12 columns in there template.

There is some template. Then you can easily find other templates and tuto to implement that.

Comment: Do *not* rely on frameworks. As I hire people I test to see whether they default to a framework or not and immediately cut them off. Do the code the *right* way the first time and you won't get stuck in maintenance hell.

Comment: I totally disagree with John. Using supported frameworks is the key of success. For exemple John, do you suggest people on using AngularJS ? BackboneJS ? or other? No? Well, you are totally missing a thing and loosing your time trying to redo (and sadly, badly done) something that hard worker have already implemented, tested, and runned in production.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want help with your task have a look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xaesuygf/1/) Not sure if this is what you were looking for but play around with it

I switched most of your `position:absolute` to `float:right`

Comment: This is a good answer, people spam the crap out of `position` when they should be using it for major layout adjustments *only* 99.9% of the time. Using `float` shows an actual understanding of how CSS is *supposed* to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something easy to use and doesn't require a lot of changes, you can also use the "framework" from here: `http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/`

It is not too heavy and only gives you what you need to make a site responsive. I am using this for a company.

Twitter bootstrap in my opinion is good but it is heavy and although most classes doesn't get loaded, changing/modifying the code is very hectic.

Comment: Yes I agree, watching tutorials on bootstrap right now, I see I would have to change a lot.

Comment: I am glad. I am using the grid system for my personal and professional client site and it is very easy to integrate and modify! Good luck.